# Tensorflow CNN sometimes converges, sometimes not

Tags: python, tensorflow, convolutional-neural-network

*originally asked on stackoverflow, deleted*

Im having trouble traing a convolutional neural network in tensorflow. When I start my program, sometimes the model learns nicely (cost/cross_entropy goes down, accuracy on training and testing data goes up) and appears to converge after 50-100 epochs.

However sometimes the training seems to get stuck after only a couple (2-4) epochs. Cost hovers around the same value (1.25) and accuracies get stuck on the same values: 0.45970 for training data and 0.016666 for testing data. No changes were made to code or training data between runs.

The "good" runs (when the model learns) converge to various final accuracies. On the other hand, every single "bad" run goes to the exact same accuracy: 0.45970.

I have 330 000 training images (grayscale), converted to numpy arrays. The generator I use to create tensorflow dataset works such as it lists all files in the folder, then takes every N-th file from that list and feeds only those selected files to the dataset. Currently Im using every 100th file, which works out to 33 batches of 100 images for a total of 3300 training images. I have 4 classes and the number of samples of each class is: 904, 321, 558, 1517.

I have tried using more training samples (33 000) and different learning rates but the result was the same. It is more often that the network has a bad run than a good run.

The only thing I can imagine is different between individual runs is the random initialization of weights, but could it have such an effect? Especially considering that random weight initialization uses small stddev (0.03/0.01)? Or is there something wrong with my code?

Accuracy/cost plots: 
[image: Graph of a bad run]
[image: Graph of a good run]

Code is in two files: main and stream_data.py, which handles loading images from disk.

Main program:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import time
import stream_data as sd    #for reading train/eval data

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'  # or any {'0', '1', '2'}        

epochs = 10000
learning_rate = 0.03

#use every 100-th training image
sd.generator_filenames_every_nth_train = 100
#use every testing image
sd.generator_filenames_every_nth_eval = 1

batch_size = 100
batch_size_eval = 100

#num training and evaluation batches per epoch - this works out to 33 training batches of 100 images and 12 batches of 100 images for evaluation
num_train_samples = len(os.listdir(sd.path_to_train_files_npy_stream))
total_batch = int(num_train_samples /( sd.generator_filenames_every_nth_train * batch_size))
print('Num training samples:', num_train_samples, 'Generator train skip:', sd.generator_filenames_every_nth_train,  'Num train batches:', total_batch)

num_eval_samples = len(os.listdir(sd.path_to_eval_files_npy_stream))
total_batch_eval = int(num_eval_samples / (sd.generator_filenames_every_nth_eval * batch_size_eval))
print('Num eval samples:', num_eval_samples, 'Generator eval skip:', sd.generator_filenames_every_nth_eval, 'Num eval batches:', total_batch_eval)                      


def run_cnn():

    #for logging results
    log_accuracy_train=[]
    log_accuracy_eval=[]
    log_cross_entropy=[]    


    # SET UP THE NETWORK
    # declare the training data placeholders
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, sd.image_width * sd.image_height * sd.num_channels_used], name='placeholder_x')
    x_shaped = tf.reshape(x, [-1, sd.image_height, sd.image_width, sd.num_channels_used], name='placeholder_x_shaped')
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, sd.num_output_classes], name='placeholder_y')

    # create some convolutional layers
    layer1 = create_new_conv_layer(x_shaped, 1, 10, [5, 5], [4, 4], [4,4], name='layer1')
    layer2 = create_new_conv_layer(layer1, 10, 20, [5, 5], [5,5], [5,5], name='layer2')

    # flatten the output ready for the fully connected output stage
    flattened = tf.reshape(layer2, [-1, 17 * 66 * 20])

    # setup some weights and bias values for this layer, then activate with ReLU
    wd1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([17 * 66 * 20, 50], stddev=0.03), name='wd1')
    bd1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([50], stddev=0.01), name='bd1')
    dense_layer1 = tf.matmul(flattened, wd1) + bd1
    dense_layer1 = tf.nn.relu(dense_layer1, name = 'dense1')

    # another layer with softmax activations - this is output layer
    wd2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([50, sd.num_output_classes], stddev=0.03), name='wd2')
    bd2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([sd.num_output_classes], stddev=0.01), name='bd2')
    dense_layer2 = tf.matmul(dense_layer1, wd2) + bd2
    y_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(dense_layer2, name='y_prediction')

    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=dense_layer2, labels=y), name='cross_entropy')

    # add an optimizer
    adam_optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate, name='adam_optimizer_var')
    optimizer = adam_optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy, name='adam_optimizer_minimize')

    # define an accuracy assessment operation
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_prediction, 1), name = 'correct_prediction')
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32), name='accuracy')

    #define how to get batches
    batch_xt, batch_yt, batch_ft = sd.get_inputs_train(batch_size)
    batch_xe, batch_ye, batch_fe = sd.get_inputs_eval(batch_size_eval)

    # setup the initialisation operator
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()


    model_saver = tf.train.Saver(name='model_saver')

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init_op)           

        #in each epoch, train all batches and then evaluate the network on testing data
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            avg_cost = 0
            avg_accuracy = 0.0
            print('Training batches in epoch', epoch)
            for i in range(total_batch):
                time_0 = timer()
                #get training data
                batch_x_np, batch_y_np, batch_f_np = sess.run([batch_xt, batch_yt, batch_ft])
                time_1 = timer()
                #train network
                _, c, train_acc = sess.run([optimizer, cross_entropy, accuracy], feed_dict={x: batch_x_np, y: batch_y_np})                  
                avg_cost += c / total_batch 
                avg_accuracy += train_acc / total_batch     
                time_2 = timer()
                print('Trained batch ', i, '/', total_batch, ' Time: {:.3f} :'.format(time_2 - time_0), '{:.3f},'.format(time_1 - time_0), '{:.3f}'.format(time_2 - time_1),'Acc: {:.3f}'.format(train_acc))
            print('After train epoch:', epoch, "train cost =", "{:.5f}".format(avg_cost), 'Avg train accuracy: {:.5f}'.format(avg_accuracy))

            #save cross correlation and accuracy after training one epoch
            log_accuracy_train = np.append(log_accuracy_train, avg_accuracy)
            log_cross_entropy = np.append(log_cross_entropy, avg_cost)
            np.save('./results/train_cost.npy',  log_cross_entropy)
            np.save('./results/train_accuracy.npy',  log_accuracy_train)

            print('Saving model after epoch', epoch)
            model_saver.save(sess, './models/merc_proper/model_merc_full', global_step = epoch, write_meta_graph = True)




            #evaluating model on testing data
            avg_accuracy=0.0
            for i in range(total_batch_eval):       
                time_0 = timer()
                #get testing data
                batch_x_np, batch_y_np, batch_f_np = sess.run([batch_xe, batch_ye, batch_fe])                               
                time_1 = timer()
                #feedforward and get accuracy
                test_acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: batch_x_np, y: batch_y_np})
                time_2 = timer()
                avg_accuracy += test_acc/total_batch_eval
                print("Epoch:", (epoch), "eval accuracy: {:.3f}".format(test_acc), ' Time: {:.3f} :'.format(time_2 - time_0), '{:.3f},'.format(time_1 - time_0), '{:.3f}'.format(time_2 - time_1))
            print('Average eval accuracy after epoch', epoch, ':', avg_accuracy)

            #save accuracy on testing data after epoch
            log_accuracy_eval = np.append(log_accuracy_eval, avg_accuracy)
            np.save('./results/eval_accuracy.npy',  log_accuracy_eval)

        print("\nTraining complete!")



def create_new_conv_layer(input_data, num_input_channels, num_filters, filter_shape, pool_shape, pool_stride, name):
    # setup the filter input shape for tf.nn.conv_2d
    conv_filt_shape = [filter_shape[0], filter_shape[1], num_input_channels, num_filters]

    # initialise weights and bias for the filter
    #orig mean=0, std=0.03
    weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(conv_filt_shape, mean=0.0, stddev=0.03), name=name+'_W')
    bias = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_filters]), name=name+'_b')

    # setup the convolutional layer operation
    out_layer = tf.nn.conv2d(input_data, weights, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

    # add the bias
    out_layer += bias

    # apply a ReLU non-linear activation
    out_layer = tf.nn.relu(out_layer)

    # now perform max pooling
    ksize = [1, pool_shape[0], pool_shape[1], 1]
    strides = [1, pool_stride[0], pool_stride[1], 1]
    out_layer = tf.nn.max_pool(out_layer, ksize=ksize, strides=strides, padding='SAME')

    return out_layer


def stop(msg = None):
    if(msg != None):
        print(msg)
    raw_input('Press ENTER to continue')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_cnn()
```

stream_data.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import os   #listdir
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import pickle 
import random
import copy
from PIL import Image
import threading


#resolution of images
image_width = 1320
image_height = 340
#number of channels - images are grayscale
num_channels_raw = 1
num_channels_used = 1

#how many images should be skipped - only every N-th image will be used
#so if this is == 100, only every 100th image will be used
generator_filenames_every_nth_train = 1
generator_filenames_every_nth_eval = 1

num_output_classes = 4
path_to_train_files_npy_stream = '/media/user/DiskNaData_1TB/data/merc/train_artificial_npy/'
path_to_eval_files_npy_stream = '/media/user/DiskNaData_1TB/data/merc/eval_artificial_npy/'


def stop(msg = None):
    if(msg != None):
        print(msg)
    raw_input('Press ENTER to continue')


#generator that produces train/eval data
#returns data (grayscale values), label(onehot) and filename (for debugging purposes)
#reads list of all files in a folder, then skips some of them and only yields every N-th 
def read_stream_files(path_to_files_npy_stream, every_nth):
    files = os.listdir(path_to_files_npy_stream)    
    for i in range(0, len(files), every_nth):
        filename=files[i]
        data = np.load(path_to_files_npy_stream + filename)

        data=data.astype(float)
        data=data / 255.0

        label = int(filename[0:2])
        #make one-hot 
        onehot = np.zeros(num_output_classes)
        onehot[label] = 1
        label=onehot
        yield data, label, filename



def get_dataset_train():
    generator = lambda: read_stream_files(path_to_train_files_npy_stream, generator_filenames_every_nth_train)
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        generator, (tf.float32, tf.int32, tf.string), ((image_width*image_height*num_channels_used,), (num_output_classes, ), ()))


def get_dataset_eval():
    generator = lambda: read_stream_files(path_to_eval_files_npy_stream, generator_filenames_every_nth_eval)
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        generator, (tf.float32, tf.int32, tf.string), ((image_width*image_height*num_channels_used,), (num_output_classes, ), ()))


def get_inputs_train(batch_size):
    dataset = get_dataset_train()  
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000)
    dataset = dataset.repeat()  # repeat indefinitely
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(3)
    features, label, filename = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    return features, label, filename


def get_inputs_eval(batch_size):
    dataset = get_dataset_eval()  # one of the above implementations
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.repeat()
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(3)
    features, label, filename = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    return features, label, filename
```

Comment: That's one complex program...Why don't you write using predefined functions and then move to manual nuts and bolts?

Comment: @DuttaA Im a beginner at using Tensorflow. My program is just a bit adapted version of tutorial at [adventuresinmachinelearning.com](http://adventuresinmachinelearning.com/convolutional-neural-networks-tutorial-tensorflow/)
The only bigger difference is the streaming of training/eval samples.